# How to assign class for all Html.LabelFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an app with about 50 of these:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentLineItem.Address.Address1, new { @class = "textBox-label" })
```

It seems to me hardcoding a class is not a good idea.  Is there a way to abstract this out further?  Like maybe:

```
@Html.LabelWithTextBoxLabelClass(m=> m.CurrentLineItem.Address.Address1);
```

Comment: You could make a custom html helper? http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Do you want to apply css for label ?

Comment: Doing it in CSS is definitely the way to go if you don't want to hard code the classes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like others said, make your own Html Helper, code like below:

```
public static class LabelExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelWithTextBoxLabelClass(this HtmlHelper helper, string expression)
    {
        return helper.Label(expression, new { @class = "textBox-label" });
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString LabelForWithTextBoxLabelClass<TModel,TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel,TValue>> expression)
    {
        return helper.LabelFor(expression, new {@class = "textBox-label"});
    }
}
```

now you can use it like what you want:

```
@Html.LabelWithTextBoxLabelClass(m=> m.CurrentLineItem.Address.Address1);
```

Comment: This is a great solution.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I don't understand, because the usage you have there only has one parameter. Shouldn't there be two?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own `Html helpers`, or you can use `Bootstrap Html Helpers` for `MVC`. Take a look at here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc

With bootstrap you can simply set your label class like this:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.Property).Class("textBox-label")
```

Comment: This isn't very helpful since you're still required to use the `.Class()` on every `Label`.